# Why volley is not sending the values?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new to android development. I'm trying to send some data to server using volley. But it is not sending parameters. Please help. The server is saying that the parameter is not set. I checked with the isset in php. When I tried sending data from a html form, it's working. But the volley is not sending the parameters.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText uname;
    EditText uotp;
    RequestQueue myqueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        uotp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uotp);

        myqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);       
    }

    public void sendotp(View v)
    {
        String unameval = uname.getText().toString();
        if(unameval.matches(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("phone", unameval);
            String myUrl = "http://privateurlhere";
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, myUrl, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String dispname = response.getString("stat");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dispname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Resp err" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            myqueue.add(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the important parts of your server side code too. LogCat showing nothing wrong?

Comment: what is the response your getting back from the server ?.